# print vs return indentation rules for python

Tags: python

consider this code

```
board = []
for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        x=" ".join(row)
        print x
        return x
```

which yields OOOOO

and this code

```
board = []
for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        x=" ".join(row)
        print x
    return x
```

which yields

```
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: The function terminates as soon as it hits a `return` statement. In your first example, this happens on the first loop. In your second, it happens after the final loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function you are `return`ing out of the loop after the first iteration, so no more `print` statements are run.

This is a demonstration of Python's "indent sensitivity", in other languages this might not make a difference due to the presence of braces; in Python, it does.